# How do I get the button I created in PageView to switch to a new page on the last page?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
 Row(
            children: [
              ...List.generate(data.length,(index) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
              child: DotIndicator(isActive: index== pageIndex),)),
              Spacer(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                  _pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease); 
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: CircleBorder(),),
                child: Image.asset('assets/arrow.png', color: Colors.white,),),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

[image]

I've designed an onboarding and I'm having a problem with the last page. I go forward with the button I created, but on the last page, the progress ends because there is no other page left. So how can I redirect to the home page of the application only when the button is clicked on the last page?

I designed the part in the lower left side of the DotIndicator. In the list, there is information such as title and image on the pages. How should I write a code for the onPressed method so that it redirects me to a new page of the application on the last page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate to or jumpto

```
_controller.animateToPage(pageIndex);

//Or

_controller.jumpToPage(pageIndex);
```

Or if you wish to navigate to someother screen then you can check index

First get index of page

```dart
int currentPage = 0;

onPageChanged: (page){
                  setState(() {
                    currentPage=page;
                  });
                },
```

Add this code to pageview..

Then in the elevated button you can check the index

```dart
child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
  if(currentPage >= 3){
    Navigator.push(context, builder: ()=>YourClass());
  }
  else{ 
   //Do next page code here to switch page in pageview
  }
 },
```

Comment: But I want to switch to a completely different widget. As far as I understand, these 2 methods allow me to navigate to different places within the same widget. I want to switch to a new widget with the MaterialPageRoute method.

Comment: I added an image to the question. I am getting this error in navigator.  When I try with MaterialPageRoute, it doesn't switch from the last page to a new widget.